# Multiple WPA Supplicant Files when trying to connect to hidden wireless network

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I tried to follow some online tutorials to get my Pi to connect to a hidden network. I used the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Prompting this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev

update_config=1
country=GB

network={
        ssid="insert_your_hidden_SSID_here"
        scan_ssid=1
        psk="insert_your_wifi_password_here"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

I ended up creating several wpa_supplicant.conf files as I was a bit confused initially what the process did. 
[image]

I have several of these files and I don't need them anymore. I tried to delete them manually just to see what would happen and I got a permission denied warning. On top of that, I wasn't able to even connect to my hidden network, so I ended up making it visible and connecting to it that way. If anyone has suggestions as to how I can remove the config files, or if I should just leave them be, and how I could properly access hidden networks, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I cannot "read" the pictures. Please paste text output direct into the question.

Comment: You should not play around that section without having a clear info. That could crash you r network interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete restricted files you can use `rm` in combination with `sudo` (execute with root rights). So to delete *wpa_supplicant.conf* you can execute on the command line:

```
rpi ~$ sudo rm /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Repeat that with the names of the other files you want to delete. But you need *wpa_supplicant.conf* to connect to the hidden access point. Just recreate `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` with the content you have shown in the question. That should do.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to see what you have done (post **text** not illegible pictures) or how you actually created multiple files, but `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` is owned by root.

It can easily be deleted at the command line with

```
sudo rm /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for detail of setting up networking.